# Execute script on the remote server , send an email from local server

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I am working on a script

This script sits on the server-A and runs on the server-B

Now I want to check if a command went fine on the remote server-B . If the command is successful , then it should sent  an email to a distribution.

This email should be coming from server-A . Now I am in a state of dilemma to understand how can we send an email from server-A , with an output of the command executed on the server-B.

Here is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
ps -ef|grep -i service
output1=$(echo $?)
if [ "$output1" -ne 0 ]
then
docker start service
fi
docker ps|grep service
output2=$(echo $?)
fi
if [ "$output2" -ne 0 ]
then
mail -s "Unable to start protegrity on $(hostname)" santoshkumar.chakilam@address.com <<< "message"
fi
```

Comment: I think that the phrasing of this question needs to be clarified. For example, what do you mean when say that the script "sits" on server-A but "runs" on server-B? I was expecting to see a script that runs a remote command, but it looks like that isn't the case.

Comment: The above script runs on a remote machine server-B. The above script is actually a subscript of a main script. So is the reason you may see it as incomplete and without any remote commands..

Comment: What are you using to execute the remote command?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the main task you're trying to accomplish is to get the output of a command executed on a remote server. Here is a minimalistic example which illustrates how to accomplish this using SSH.

First, create a script to run on the remote server:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# remote_script.sh

echo "This ran on the remote server!"
```

Next, create a script to run on the local server which calls the script on the remote server:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# local_script.sh

output="$(ssh user@remote_server "bash remote_script.sh")"
echo ${output}
```

Finally, run the local script:

```
user@local_server:~$ bash local_script.sh
"This ran on the remote server!"
```